# How can I align Bulma's level items horizontally on smaller screens?

Tags: css, bulma

The footer of my website contains a `level` layout with a left and right part according to the [Bulma docs](https://bulma.io/documentation/layout/level/). On larger screens this is fine.

On smaller screens however all items of the right part get stacked vertically. Whereas I'd like them to be aligned horizontally and centered as in the following image.

Please see this example:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aVdPPy

[image: sample screenshot]

Comment: *"By default, for space concerns, the level is vertical on mobile. If you want the level to be horizontal on mobile as well, add the `is-mobile` modifier on the `level` container."*

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm aware of the `is-mobile` modifier but this applies to the complete `level`. I'd think of something like a `is-mobile` modifier for the right level only, e.g. `class="level-right is-mobile"` but this does not exist as far as I can see.

Comment: In that case I think you'd have to update the `level-right` elements in your own CSS, or take the `level-item` classes off the `a`nchor elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have 2 options here.

### Option 1

Add the `.is-mobile` modifier to `.level` and then add some additional CSS to stack `.level-left` and `.level-right`.

```
.level.is-mobile {
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

### Option 2

Alternatively, add the `.is-flex-mobile` modifier to `level-right`, and add additional CSS to override the `justify-content` property:

```
.level-right.is-flex-mobile {
  justify-content: center;
}
```